# Why is count i slower than count sym for partitioned tables

Tags: kdb

I heard somewhere that running `select count i from tbl where date = .z.d-1` is slower than `select count sym from tbl where date = .z.d-1` when querying partitioned tables as `count i` creates a virtual column. Is this true, and if so why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If just doing `count i` without any aggregation then it will probably be quicker.

I've created an example `quote` tables with 10 million entries for a single date, querying for count is quicker with `i`:

```
q)\ts:1000 select count i from quote where date=.z.d
5 1712
q)\ts:1000 select count sym from quote where date=.z.d
44 2512
```

I can't find the documentation for it but I *think* this may be one of those under the hood optimisations.

If aggregating using `by` then using `i` will be slower as the virtual column must be created. This can be tested:

```
q)\ts select count i by sym from quote where date=.z.d
57 134222240

q)\ts select count ask by sym from quote where date=.z.d
0 6672
```

So yes, it is true that performance is worse for `count i` when aggregating for the reason mentioned, the virtual column must be created beforehand.

Comment: The optimisation is in `.Q.ps` (partitioned select) and takes effect if the select phrase is only `count i` or just the partition column (e.g. `date`), the where phrase only filters on the partition column and by phrase is either absent or aggregating by partition column. The optimisation uses `.Q.cn` https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#cn-count-partitioned-table which will be a little slower on first run as it has to populate `.Q.pn` cache, but after cache is populated, it will be very fast.